# Share object only between nested classes

Tags: python, class

First of all I know that the code below is ridiculous and can be a simple loop but I want to understand if/how I can do some things in Nested Classes:

```
class OuterClass(object):
    counter = 0  # Class variable

    def __init__(self, v):
        super(OuterClass, self).__init__()
        self.values = v # Instance variable
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        for v in values:
            self.NestedClass(v)  # can I bound a nested class to the outer?
        print self.NestedClass.size


    class NestedClass(object):
        size = 0     # Nested Class variable

        def __init__(self, value):
            super(NestedClass, self).__init__()  # NameError: global name 'NestedClass' is not defined
            NestedClass.size += 1     # Nested Instance variable
```

My purpose is for every OuterClass instance to create a class of NestedClass. **So I want the `size` to be different for every OuterClass instance.**

How can I fix the last two lines:

```
super(NestedClass, self).__init__()
NestedClass.size += 1
```

- If I write `self.NestedClass.size` it will try find a the NestedClass inside itself and throw an error.
- If I write `OuterClass.NestedClass.size` it will be bound to the outer class and the size will be the same object among OuterClass instances (I don't want this).
- I also tried `OuterClass.self.NestedClass.size` with `AttributeError: type object 'OuterClass' has no attribute 'self'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... the size will be the same object among OuterClass instances (I don't want this).

As long as `size` is a class-member of `NestedClass`, it only exists once. This is because there is only one class `NestedClass`, and `size` is a member of that class.

If you want a `size` member for each instance, well, that's what instance-members are for...

Comment: You are correct. I was trying to make the result inside the inner class w/o putting any effort to return results from inner to outer class. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you do the following:

```
>>> class Outer:
...   class Inner:
...     nb = 0
...     def __init__(self):
...       Outer.Inner.nb += 1
...   def test(self):
...     t = self.Inner()
...     print(t.nb)
... 
>>> o = Outer()
>>> o.test()
1
>>> o.test()
2
>>> o.test()
3
```

you're creating a class variable that will be bound the the class `Outer.Inner` and
each time you modify it, it changes for *all* instances of that class.

> *My purpose is for every OuterClass instance to create a class of NestedClass. So I want the size to be different for every OuterClass instance.*

If you want to have that variable dependant on each `Outer` instance, you need
to create a reflexion to `Outer` on `Inner`:

```
>>> class Outer:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.nb = 0
...   class Inner:
...     def __init__(self, o):
...       o.nb += 1
...   def test(self):
...     t = self.Inner(self)
...     print(self.nb)
... 
>>> o = Outer()
>>> o.test()
1
>>> o.test()
2
>>> o.test()
3
>>> o2 = Outer()
>>> o2.test()
1
>>> o2.test()
2
>>> o2.test()
3
>>>
```

that way the variable is an instance member for each `Outer` instance, and modified
by every `Inner` instance.

Comment: outer is spelled with one t only

Comment: thank you, I'm fixing this.